# Bootstrap-4 no padding nav

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item-dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                SLIDES
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="Preview">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Événements Importants</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rappels des bonnes pratiques</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ecran Sonar</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item-dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                BANDEAU
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="Preview">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rappel CRA</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Visite Client</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Nouvelle version</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">POP-UP</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Here's my code

The problem is that there's no padding, is it normal ? Here's a picture of what it renders :

http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/248061Screenshotfrom20160804155752.png

Other problem is that it can display you 2 links on the same line :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fail to make your dropdown work, but you can add some padding to your `a` elements like this:

**In HTML:**

```
...
<a class="dropdown-item pad15" href="#">Événements Importants</a>
...
```

**In CSS:**

```
.pad15 {
    padding: 15px;
}
```

---

It is very simple, but I guess it is what you are looking for.

---

**UPDATE:** Without CSS file

```
...
<a class="dropdown-item" style="padding:15px;" href="#">Événements Importants</a>
...
```

Comment: I would like to be able doing it without making a css file :/ But thanks for the solution ;)

Comment: So you can use `style` in your HTML attribute to set your padding. Updated my answer.

Comment: Why didn't I think about it xD Thanks !

Comment: Even easier for Bootstrap 4 stable: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/